# Convert object array list into csv string using C#

Tags: c#, csv, salesforce, bulkupdate

I have a list of an object Person type. I need to convert it to a csv string so as to process further. What I have done till now is :

overrided `toString` method as below :

```
public override string ToString()
  {
   return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", userame, firstname, lastname, marks);
  }
```

sample implementation:

```
string csv = String.Join(",", detailList.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("csv  " + csv);
```

This is not the valid format I know. Can anyone help me out in converting to a proper csv fromat ?

I need this csv to use in salesforce Bulk API.

UPDT : My desired output is -

FirstName,LastName,Username

"Tom","Jones","Tom1234"

"Jack","Smith","Jack123"

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason to override Tostring() method?

Comment: Without overriding it will not return the list in readable format.

Comment: Try writing an example of you desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(",", detailList.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

See working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KJVYqC

```
public class CsvFormatter
{
    public string Format(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine("FirstName,LastName,Username");

        foreach(var person in persons)
        {
            sb.Append(person.Firstname + ",");
            sb.Append(person.Lastname + ",");   
            sb.Append(person.Username);

            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```